# É possível contabilizar visitantes de busca orgânica?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se há alguma ferramenta/api para saber a partir de que site o visitante veio, para contabilizar os visitantes vindos dos motores de busca. Obrigado à todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`HTTP_REFERER`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>
> O endereço da página (se houver) através da qual o agente do usuário acessou a página atual. Essa diretiva é informada pelo agente do usuário. **Nem todos os browsers geram esse header**, e **alguns ainda possuem a habilidade de modificar o conteúdo do HTTP_REFERER** como recurso. Em poucas palavras, não é confiável.

---

Basta usar como abaixo, mas não confie nestes dados.

```
$origem = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;
```